# How to get hidden value field in Codeigniter Controller Layer

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In Codeigniter PHP, I need to add a hidden field value to the database.

In my View Layer, I have

`form_hidden(name,value);`

I need to add this to a table through my controller linking to my model.
Normally, for text box inputs, to get values I use

`this->input->post('name')`.

However for hidden values, this does not seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to show your code and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example using form in CI 3.0

In view:

```
<?php echo form_open();?>
  <?php echo form_hidden('_hidden_field','TEST');?>
  <?php echo form_input('username', 'John');?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

In controller:

```
  ...
  if($this->input->post()) {
    echo $this->input->post('_hidden_field').'<br/>';
    echo $this->input->post('username');
  }
  ...
```

Result:

```
TEST
John
```

You try! :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure the form helper is loaded.

You can do this in your controller

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

**OR** through the auto-load feature(if used excessively)

```
$autoload['helpers'] = array('form');
```

To quickly add hidden fields, you can simply add an array of hidden fields as the third parameter to the `form_open` method

```
form_open('controller/method', array(id=>'myFormID'), array('my_hidden_field'=>12345));
```

To fetch the hidden field, simply use:

```
$this->input->post('my_hidden_field');
```